# CentOS 7 PHP7 Curl: (58) SSL Peer rejected your certificate as expired. But works fine on Windows

Tags: php, linux, ssl, curl

Migrating to CentOS 7 from Windows server 2012.  PHP7 with curl. When running on Windows my pkcs12 pem certificate with private key works fine, connects returns the relevant data. However, on CentOS 7 I get a 
**curl: (58) SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired**
, along with this read error:
**SSL read: errno -12269 (SSL_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERT_ALERT**)

As of this post the Certificate Was not expired.  Replacing before expire date, Please assume that the cert is Not Expired.

verbose results as followed

```
 Trying 148.142.64.105...

Connected to markets.midwestiso.org (148.142.64.105) port 443 (#0)

 Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb

 skipping SSL peer certificate verification

 SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

 Server certificate:       
 subject: CN=markets.midwestiso.org,O=Midwest ISO,L=Carmel,ST=Indiana,C=US
       start date: Aug 09 13:31:46 2016 GMT
       expire date: Aug 25 14:01:45 2019 GMT
       common name: markets.midwestiso.org
       issuer: CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K,OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only",OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O="Entrust, Inc.",C=US

POST /darteor/xml/query HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) 

Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1

Host: markets.midwestiso.org

Accept: */*

Content-Length: 375

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

upload completely sent off: 375 out of 375 bytes

skipping SSL peer certificate verification

NSS: client certificate from file
       subject: UID=xxxxx,E=xxx,CN=xxx,OU=xx,O=xx,C=xx
       **start date: Nov 02 15:38:21 2015 GMT
       expire date: Nov 01 15:38:21 2016 GMT**
       common name: xx
       issuer: xx

SSL read: errno -12269 (SSL_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERT_ALERT)

SSL peer rejected your certificate as expired.

Closing connection 0
```

the curl_getinfo is as follows:

```
[url] => https://markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/query
[content_type] =>
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 621
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.478578
[namelookup_time] => 0.060583
[connect_time] => 0.106785
[pretransfer_time] => 0.304066
[size_upload] => 375
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 783
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 375
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] =>
[primary_ip] => 148.142.64.105
[certinfo] => Array
    (
       "Not sure why blank here, seems like a bug"
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.x.x.x
[local_port] => 43352
```

PHP 7 Curl Code is as follows:

```
  $interval = '2016-10-18';

  $cert1 = '/xxx/xxx/xxx.pem'; //contains the private key
  $pass1 = 'xxxx';


  $soapreq ='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header/>
  <Body>
    <QueryRequest xmlns="http://markets.midwestiso.org/dart/xml" party="xxx">
     <QueryRealTimeIntegratedLMP day="'.$interval.'">
        <All/>
     </QueryRealTimeIntegratedLMP>
    </QueryRequest>
  </Body>
</Envelope>';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/query");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pass1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapreq);

    echo $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "\n".$err = curl_errno($ch);
    echo "\n";
    print_r($info);

    $certInfo   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CERTINFO);
    print_r($certInfo);
```

I am currently very stuck, and would love a little guidance

Thanks

Comment: "peer rejected" are you sure the clock on the other end is correct?

Comment: Your certificate expire for week. Check date as suggest @MarcB. And I suggest you to renew certificate before date over.

Comment: This is an error message created by the server which means that it will not help much to look at the client. But it might be that the SSL alert does not address a problem of your leaf certificate but of some chain certificate. I suggest you do a packet capture to compare the handshake done by the windows and the CentOS client, especially which certificates (and chains) are actually sent.

Comment: Yes the date is correct and running via ntp.

Comment: Wouldn't the chain (ca) be irrelevant if I have **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);** and am explicitly providing the cert.  Again this works perfectly fine on Windows currently

Comment: Ok so why would a pem format cert that contains the entire chain and the private key not be working the same FROM a linux system the FROM a windows system using curl.  I am still lost here.  seems like if the cert not being installed on the windows system, and is sent successfully, then why would doing the same thing on a linux system with the same code fail.  I suck at tls!!